# Why is testbed not flushing the datastore on TearDown() and why environ values aren't passed to the code I'm testing?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-unittest, testbed

I'm trying to setup unittests for my App Engine tutorial example.

I have defined the user in self.testbed.setup_env but the data is not visible in the tested code. Somehow, despite this data not being rendered by the print statement, it's being saved as a structured property in the datastore and is not deleted in the TearDown().

**The code works when I use dev_appserver.py and enter the data into the form manually.**
When I attempt to run the tests with **nosetests --with-gae**, the mock user data is not not available
Since I'm attempting to debug a test, I can't use a debugger and I'm relying on print statements.

```
 import sys, os, subprocess, time, unittest, shlex     
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")   
 sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/')     
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")      
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")      

 os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'] = 'myapp'   

 from selenium import webdriver      
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  

 from google.appengine.api import memcache, apiproxy_stub, apiproxy_stub_map       
 from google.appengine.ext import testbed      
 from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util       
 from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2      

 from guestbook import Author, Greeting    
 from google.appengine.api import users  

 class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):      
     # enable the datastore stub  
     nosegae_datastore_v3 = True  
     nosegae_datastore_v3_kwargs = {  
         'datastore_file': '/tmp/nosegae.sqlite3',  
         'use_sqlite': True  
     }  

     def setUp(self):      
         # Start the dev server     
         cmd = "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py /Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/guestbook/app.yaml --port 8080 --storage_path /tmp/datastore --clear_datastore --skip_sdk_update_check"    
         self.dev_appserver = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),     
                                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE)    
         time.sleep(2) # Important, let dev_appserver start up    


         self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()  
         self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='guestbook')      
         self.testbed.activate()      
         self.datastore_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('datastore_v3')               
         # setup the dev_appserver      
         APP_CONFIGS = ['app.yaml']      

         self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()      
         self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)      
 #               
     def tearDown(self):   
         self.testbed.deactivate()     
         self.browser.quit()     
         self.dev_appserver.terminate()    

     def loginUser(self, email="elonMusk@example.com", id='123456', is_admin=False):  
         self.testbed.setup_env(  
             user_email=email,  
             user_id=id,  
             user_is_admin='1' if is_admin else '0',  
             overwrite=True  
         )  
         self.testbed.init_user_stub()  

     def test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author(self):  

          self.browser.get('http://localhost:8080')  
          self.loginUser()  

          self.browser.find_element_by_name('content').send_keys("Test Driven Development is awesome!!!")  
          self.browser.find_element_by_id('submit_guestbook').submit()  
          # Can I access them via querys on the database?  
          assert("Test Driven Development is awesome!!!" in self.browser.page_source)  
          self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/datastore')  
          assert(Greeting.query(Greeting.author.email=='elonMusk@example.com').get())  
          self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/datastore')  
          # I'm opening the datastore to see that the entity is saved.  
          # The entity is saved but the Author property is empty.  
          time.sleep(10) # this gives me time to view the datastore in browser.    

          self.assertEqual(1, Greeting.query().count())
```

Here is questbook.py:
    import os
    import urllib

```
from google.appengine.api import users  
from google.appengine.ext import ndb  

import jinja2  
import webapp2  

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(  
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),  
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],  
    autoescape=True)  

DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'default_guestbook'  


# We set a parent key on the 'Greetings' to ensure that they are all  
# in the same entity group. Queries across the single entity group  
# will be consistent. However, the write rate should be limited to  
# ~1/second.  

def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):  
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity.  
    We use guestbook_name as the key.  
    """  
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)  


class Author(ndb.Model):  
    """Sub model for representing an author."""  
    identity = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)  
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)  


class Greeting(ndb.Model):  
    """A main model for representing an individual Guestbook entry."""  
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)  
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)  
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)  


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):  

    def get(self):  
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',  
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)  
        greetings_query = Greeting.query(  
            ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)  
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)  

        user = users.get_current_user()  
        if user:  
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)  
            url_linktext = 'Logout'  
        else:  
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)  
            url_linktext = 'Login'  

        template_values = {  
            'user': user,  
            'greetings': greetings,  
            'guestbook_name': urllib.quote_plus(guestbook_name),  
            'url': url,  
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,  
        }  

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')  
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))  


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):  

    def post(self):  
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',  
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)  
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))  
        if users.get_current_user():  
            greeting.author = Author(  
                    identity=users.get_current_user().user_id(),  
                    email=users.get_current_user().email())  

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')  
        ######################################  
        import os  
        print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX guestbook in post() USER_EMAIL: %s" % os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL'))  
        #print("xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxox guestbook greeting.author.email: %s" % greeting.author.email )  
        greeting_key = greeting.put()  

        query_params = {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}  
        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))  


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([  
    ('/', MainPage),  
    ('/sign', Guestbook),  
], debug=False)
```

Comment: I've only run http handler unit tests with a Flask app, but not had any problems using the approach described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting). Have you tried adding `ndb.get_context().clear_cache() # This prevents data from leaking between tests` to your `tearDown()`?

Comment: I spent an enormous amount of time trying to get testbed to work with `dev_appserver.py` and concluded that you just can't use the two together.  Now I have (1) Selenium tests with `dev_appserver.py` that don't use testbed and (2) unit tests that use testbed and nose-gae.

Comment: Can you share links to some code examples of both types of tests?
I have had a hard time finding examples and the debugger not working for tests makes it hard to discern what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The datastore you can access from your test suite (the datastore_stub "mock" datastore) is not the same as the one the dev_appserver uses in your example. Hence changes to one of two datastores (such as adding an entity) will not be reflected in the other one, which is why your `Greeting.query()` returns nothing.

Instead of running a full blown, separate dev_appserver process, you can write your tests using the `webtest` framework (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/testapp.html) which will be simpler than having to manage a separate process; it will look this:

```
def setUp(self):
    [...]
    self.web_app = webtest.TestApp(guestbook.application)

[...]

def test_get(self):
    response = self.web_app.get('/')
```